# Is there a script to find every cell within a specific column that contains an asterisk, and then insert a row above it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of Questions and Answers, all of which is in column A, which includes Markdown-formatted headers. Is there a script which will identify, every cell that has an asterisk in it, and then insert a row above it?

I've tried creating a range and then using `insertRowsBefore`, but I'm getting an error (I think because `insertRowsBefore` requires an integer).

Comment: You'll need to loop through each range  with `*` and add a row above it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is what you need. This code insert a row before only when the cell 'A' in the row contains an asterisk and a row before doesn't empty.

```
function userActionInsertRowsBefore() {
  /** @type {conditionCallback} */
  var cb = function(row, i, values) {
    return values[i - 1] && /\*/.test(row[0]) && values[i - 1].join('') !== '';
  };

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  insertRowBeforeByCondition_(sheet, cb);
}

/**
 * Insert row before by a condition
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} sheet
 * @param {conditionCallback} Decides insert or skip the row
 * @returns {GoogleApps Script.Spreadsheet.Sheet}
 */

function insertRowBeforeByCondition_(sheet, condition) {
  // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (condition(values[i], i, values)) sheet.insertRowBefore(i + 1);
  }
  return sheet;
}

/**
 * This callback is displayed as a global member.
 * @callback conditionCallback
 * @param {object[]} row Row data
 * @param {number} index Index of the row
 * @param {object[][]} values Sheet values
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
```